# Naming convention for Eloquent relation method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm confused about how I should name my Method in a model. I know in Laravel Eloquent documentation it supposes to be Plural but in some case, it gives me errors. for example, i have this query:

```
$posts = Post::with(['comments','user', 'tag'])->findOrFail($id);
```

and then i print the results like this:

```
    echo "<h1>".$posts->title.'</h1>';
    echo "<h2> created by: ".$posts->user->name.'</h2>';
    echo "<p>".$posts->body."</p>";
    //echo $posts->comments;
    echo '<h3>Komentar :</h3>';
    foreach ($posts->comments as $comment) {
        echo $comment->body.'<br>';
    }
    echo '<h3>Tags :</h3>';
    foreach ($posts->tags as $tag) {
        echo '<a href="/tag/'. $tag->id .'">'.$tag->name.'</a><br>';
    }
```

it give me an errors:

```
"Call to undefined relationship [tag] on model [App\Post]."
```

but when i change my "tags" function inside Post Model into just "tag" the problems are gone. so can anybody explain what is it any name convention for this? thanks.

for more information here's my post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your POST model too.

Comment: done. i added my model into question.

Comment: Because your relationship was named 'tags' not 'tag'...  You use the relationship name in with().  You can name them however you want, just be consistent.

Comment: About naming convention, its pretty straight forward. There is not any hack in this. You will access relations with their defined names in the model.

Comment: @JunaidAhmad ah now it's clear to me now. Thanks.

Comment: @Henra Cheers :)

Comment: @JunaidAhmad when i change 'user' into 'users' it gives me an error like this:  "Trying to get property of non-object". do you know what gives me this problem?

Comment: I think you solved the problem. I just read the comments below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using just singular here `$posts = Post::with(['comments','user', 'tag'])->findOrFail($id);`

And you are using plural here `foreach ($posts->tags as $tag) {`

Try using plural in your first example as well: `Post::with(['comments','user', 'tags'])`

Comment: it works. i will select your answer in next 5 minutes, thanks.

Comment: oh now I've got some errors when I change my 'users' into user do you know what happened?

Comment: Where exactly are you changing "users" to "user"? In your example I'm only seeing the singular form.

Comment: i update the question with the full code now, please take a look. Thanks

Comment: I see, it should definitely be `$posts->user->name` when you display who created the post. What errors are you getting related to the user?

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: That means your post doesn't have a valid user attached. Check in the database and see if the post has a valid user_id, and if it points to a valid user. Hope this makes sense

Comment: well, i have user_id with it. well, it works fine when I just use 'user' and it gives me the names.

Comment: If it works with user then it's good. It should be `$posts->user` and not `$posts->users`. It makes sense in this case to be singular because a post only has a single user, but it can have multiple tags.

Comment: so it makes me have a plural and singular function name, is it no name convention for it? it really makes me have to guest for the name of my functions.

Comment: The name you use after `$posts->` ties directly to the function names from the Post class. If you look closely, in the Post class you have `comments()`, `user()`, and `tags()`. So in this case you can do `$posts->comments`, `$posts->user`, and `$posts->tags` respectively to access the 3 related models. Comments and tags can be multiple (hence the hasMany / belongsToMany relation). User can only be 1 (hence the belongsTo relation).